# A regular expression that will allow a string with only one Capital Letter

Tags: c#, regex, string

The string should be 6 - 20 characters in length.
And it should contain 1 Capital letter.

I can do this in code using C#:

```
string  st = "SomeString"

Regex rg = new Regex("[A-Z]");
MatchCollection mc = rg.Matches(st);

Console.WriteLine("Total Capital Letters: " + mc.Count);

if (mc.Count > 1)
{
  return false;
}
```

But what i really want is a Regular expression that will match my string if it only contains one capital. 
The string can start with a common letter and should have only letters.

Answer (score 7):

This one will match a string that contains lowercase letters, then a single capital letter, then more lowercase letters.

```
^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

You can adjust the first and last parts to include other characters as necessary, depending on your required character domain.

For all strings of length 6 to 20, containing only letters and at most one capital letter, you can use lookaheads:

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z]{6,20}$)^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

Comment: Add a positive look ahead to enforce the 6-20 char limit

Comment: This will actually accept any string with exactly one capital. This includes strings with no lower case chars.

Comment: At first you didn't have the look ahead... now it's there, but I don't see a "edited x minutes ago". Am I losing my mind?

Comment: @torak - No, it'll work if the Regex Options are not set to CaseInsensitive.

Comment: I'm just really fast. :) Had to verify my regex was right before I posted the lookahead solution.

Comment: @Timothy Khouri - In the original answer's the '*'s in "^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$" can match 0 or more. Now that the positive look ahead is added, it resolves the issue.

Comment: You can shorten it: ^(?=.{6,20}$)[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$

Comment: I like your first regex. I would combine it with a separate length check. Lookaheads aren't part of real regexes anyway - and they're not especially fast either.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I tried the lookaheads but did not get far writing it myself. I will try to look at Welbog submission and reverse engineer. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 4):

### regex

```
/(?=^\w{6,20}$)(?=\w*[A-Z])^\w+$/
```

### tests

```
a                       # fail
aX                      # fail
ab                      # fail
aXb                     # fail
abc                     # fail
abXc                    # fail
abcd                    # fail
abcXd                   # fail
abcde                   # fail
abcdXe                  # pass
abcdef                  # fail
abcdeXf                 # pass
abcdefg                 # fail
abXcdefg                # pass
abcdefgh                # fail
abcXdefgh               # pass
abcdefghi               # fail
abcdXefghi              # pass
abcdefghij              # fail
abcdeXfghij             # pass
abcdefghijk             # fail
abcdefXghijk            # pass
abcdefghijkl            # fail
abcdefgXhijkl           # pass
abcdefghijklm           # fail
abcdefghXijklm          # pass
abcdefghijklmn          # fail
abcXdefghijklmn         # pass
abcdefghijklmno         # fail
abcdXefghijklmno        # pass
abcdefghijklmnop        # fail
abcdeXfghijklmnop       # pass
abcdefghijklmnopq       # fail
abcdefXghijklmnopq      # pass
abcdefghijklmnopqr      # fail
abcdefgXhijklmnopqr     # pass
abcdefghijklmnopqrs     # fail
abcdefghXijklmnopqrs    # pass
abcdefghijklmnopqrst    # fail
abcdefghiXjklmnopqrst   # fail
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu   # fail
abcdefghijXklmnopqrstu  # fail
```

### regex explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w{6,20}                 word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                             (between 6 and 20 times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: What tool did you use for the explanation?

Comment: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Cd%2B(.%5Cd%2B)%3F(%5BeE%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F